# Rails Regexp::IGNORECASE while matching exact options with number options also included in the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ignore-case

I want to match the options between two arrays with exact string.

```
options = ["arish1", "arish2", "ARISH3", "arish 2", "arish"]
choices = ["Arish"]
final_choice = options.grep(Regexp.new(choices.join('|'), Regexp::IGNORECASE))
p final_choice

Output:
 ["arish1", "arish2", "ARISH3", "arish 2", "arish"]

but it should be only match "arish"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```rb
final_choice = options.grep(/\A(?:#{Regexp.union(choices).source})\z/i)
```

See the [Ruby online demo](https://ideone.com/UGtONx).

Note:

- A regex literal notation is much tidier than the constructor notation
- You can still use a variable inside the regex literal
- The [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) method joins the alternatives in `choices` using `|` "or" regex operator and escapes the items as necessary *automatically*
- `\A` anchor matches the start of stirng and `\z` matches the end of stirng.
- The non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, is used to make sure the anchors are applied to each alternative in `choices` separately.
- [`.source`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source) is used to obtain just the *pattern* part from the regex.